# Disable pull request analysis for sonarcloud.io when SonarCloud Automatic Analysis is used

Tags: sonarcloud

Is there a way to disable pull request analysis for sonarcloud.io when SonarCloud Automatic Analysis is used for a Github repository?

I need the long-lived branches analysis only, but I get all team PR's analyzed.

What's the way to disable analysis for the PRs?

Answer (score 2):

For your problem you have to **disable automatic analysis** of your code with sonarcloud (you have switch possiblity in settings of your project overview).

And next steps is to create github actions with SONAR_TOKEN to analysis only what you want and when you want.

I link the documentation about this : https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/ci-based-analysis/github-actions-for-sonarcloud/.

Enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

you have just to disable automatic analysis of your code with sonarcloud

[image]